# Dynamically create the objects by the full names specified in a file

Tags: scala, dynamic, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have some objects I want to plug in dynamically to my Play application. And one main object which  supervisors them:

```
trait MyObjectTrait {
  def run(): Unit
}

object MyObject1 extends MyObjectTrait {
  //......
}

object MyObject2 extends MyObjectTrait {
  //......
}

object MyObject3 extends MyObjectTrait {
  //......
}

object Manager {
  def runAll(): Unit = {
    val objects = getObjects()
    objects foreach run
  }
}
```

I want to be able be define which of those are active in my app by specifying them in a config file:

```
<objectsToRun>
  <add name="obj1" fullName="myapp.modules.module1.MyObject1" />
  <add name="obj2" fullName="myapp.modules.module112.MyObject2" />
  <add name="obj3" fullName="myapp.modules.module143.MyObject434" />
  <add name="obj4" fullName="myapp.modules.module14343.MyObject66" />
</objectsToRun>
```

The thing to note is, `Manager.runAll` will be used pretty often, about 1 time / minute. So I'd like to cache the dynamically **created** objects (not the result of **run** of each of them) read from config. Note that the list of the object **won't** change frequently, most of the time it'll be the same.

1. What's the idiomatic way to do this?
2. What's file should I use where I can write down the objects I want to create?
3. How do I dynamically create an object and cache it?

Answer (score 2):

Well normally for such things: [Spring's](http://spring.io/) dependency injection sounds perfect, where spring creates beans and provides it directly without worry about parsing file's and etc. Though it might/not be appropriate in your case. Depends on the scale of the project and how much do you really need it. In play, I am not sure of the *perfect* way to do it (Someone else can give their input).

> How do I dynamically create an object and cache it?

Well the class loader is smart enough to solve this for you and will only load classes (and hence the singleton object) when they are used for the first time. For example consider below:

```
object T{
        def main(args:Array[String]){
                println("1")
                println(E.num);
        }
}

object E{
        println("hey")
        def num = 23
}
```

On running:

```
jatinpuri@jatin:~/Documents/temp$ scala T
1
hey
23
```

You see `hey` is only printed when `E` is used for the first time. So the answer is: you do not need to worry about dynamically creating it, just use it when you need it.

> What's file should I use where I can write down the objects I want to
>   create?

Well again depends on how what more you have on that file. For simplicity json? And then I would:

```
object Manager {
  lazy val ls = //list of all `objectsToRun` after reading from file
  lazy val objects = ls.map{x => x match {
      case "MyObject1" => whatever.package.MyObject1
      case ...
  }}

  def runAll(): Unit = {
    objects foreach run
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm question is also about how to cache this "lazy val ls = //list of all `objectsToRun` after reading from file" call?

Comment: moreover, case "MyObject1" => whatever.package.MyObject1 implies I must know the names initially. That's hard code and not DRY. what if I don't know the names initially?